PDFThumbnailView overlaps the PDFView
I want to create a PDFView with embedded PDFThumbnailView for macOS. The PDFThumbnailView should be vertical, on the right side of the PDFView. I wish both views to be inside one NSViewRepresentable. However, I'm not very familiar with UIKit and its constraints and the best I could possibly do is to make the PDFThumbnailView overlap the PDFView. How to make the PDFView and the PDFThumbnailView separate, so they don't overlap? Here's the code:
struct PDFViewWrapper: NSViewRepresentable {

   let pdfView = PDFView()

   @Binding var pdfDisplay: Int
   
   func makeNSView(context: Context) -> PDFView  {
    
       let fileURL = FileManagerClient.shared.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("example.PDF")
    
       let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: fileURL)
    
    
    ///
       let thumbnailView = PDFThumbnailView()
       thumbnailView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       pdfView.addSubview(thumbnailView)
       thumbnailView.pdfView = pdfView
    
       NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
        [
            thumbnailView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            thumbnailView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            thumbnailView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            thumbnailView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            
        ]
    )

       thumbnailView.thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
       thumbnailView.backgroundColor = .placeholderTextColor
    ///
    
    
       pdfView.document = pdfDocument
       pdfView.autoScales = true
       pdfView.displayMode = PDFDisplayMode(rawValue: pdfDisplay) ?? .singlePageContinuous
    
    
    
    
       return pdfView
   }
   
   func updateNSView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {}

}



Why not use SwiftUI’s layout and put them in separate representables?

Could not link the two views, so they update each other. The thumbnail view for some reason was always empty.

You can put the thumbnail view and the pdf view in a horizontal NSStackView.
You can write a NSView subclass for that.
class PdfViewWithThumbnails: NSView {
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    let pdfThumbnails = PDFThumbnailView()
    
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        pdfThumbnails.thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        pdfThumbnails.backgroundColor = .placeholderTextColor
        pdfThumbnails.pdfView = pdfView
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        
        let stackView = NSStackView(views: [pdfThumbnails, pdfView])
        stackView.orientation = .horizontal
        addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // fix the width of the thumbnail
            pdfThumbnails.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            // pin the stack view to all four edges of PdfViewWithThumbnails
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

struct PDFViewWrapper: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL
    let pdfDisplay: PDFDisplayMode

     // you should not initialise the pdf view here. do it in makeNSView instead
     // otherwise this would cause a lot of needless allocations
     // every SwiftUI view update
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> PdfViewWithThumbnails  {
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url)
        let pdfWithThumbnails = PdfViewWithThumbnails()
        pdfWithThumbnails.pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        pdfWithThumbnails.pdfView.displayMode = pdfDisplay
        return pdfWithThumbnails
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsview: PdfViewWithThumbnails, context: Context) {
        // this is where you update the AppKit views to respond to a SwiftUI view update
        if nsview.pdfView.document?.documentURL != url {
            nsview.pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
        }
        nsview.pdfView.displayMode = pdfDisplay
    }
}

